# Difference in kafka 0.8 with kafka 0.10

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

Can anybody list out basic differentiating features in Kafka 0.10 as compared to kafka 0.8.

We are thinking of upgrading our kafka-8 to kafka-10. What challenges can one face in upgrading?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply identify the upgrade changes and effects if you're willing to upgrade it to 0.10.

[Upgrading from 0.8.x to 0.10.0.0](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#upgrade_10)

Comment: Thanku kulasangar. I was actually expecting some self experiences apart from what is listed. Anyways...i shall post it here after i do it.

Comment: I was already running `Kafka 10` that's why I couldn't post up any experience. Hope someone does. Yup sure would be great.

Comment: We are planning to upgrade from 0.8.0 to 0.10.0. Any pitfalls from personal experience as @Nilotpal mentioned above.

Answer (score 7):

0.10 adds the following over 0.8

- Kafka Streams API
- Kafka Connect API
- new unified Consumer API
- transport encryption using TLS/SSL
- Kerberos/SASL Authentication support
- Access Control Lists
- timestamps on messages
- reduced client dependence on zookeeper (offsets stored in Kafka topic)
- client interceptors
- lots and lots of bug fixes and improvements

Answer (score 3):

This major issue has been fixed in 0.10:

The memory and bandwidth utilization of 0.9 clients is very high. Such issues were causing spike in resource utilization by the kafka brokers.
P.S.: https://github.com/elodina/go_kafka_client/issues/52

Answer (score 1):

Kafka 0.10 changes

- Zookeeper connections are discouraged .
  From 0.10 there won't be any zookeeper connections required . All connections for consuming data will be maintained by consumer API
- zookeeper consumer config path will not have any offset lag data
- Kafka streams API and connect API has been introduced
- in Kafka 0.11 transactions have been introduced which enables Kafka to have exactly once delivery
- for monitoring offsets there is a new class KafkaConsumerGroup command class